# Missing EVP_PKEY_base_id after upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04

Tags: upgrade, openssl

I used to develop a SWIFT application on ubuntu 20. After upgrading to Jammy Jellyfish I was not able to build the application. As I found out OpenSSL was updated from 1.x to 3.x.

As mentioned in [OpenSSL Docs](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/EVP_PKEY_base_id.html) it's only deprecated, but somehow it's not in scope anymore.

```
.build/checkouts/Perfect-Crypto/Sources/PerfectCrypto/Keys.swift:61:16: error: cannot find 'EVP_PKEY_base_id' in scope
let typeId = EVP_PKEY_base_id(pkey)
```

Those dependencies are installed on machine: libssl-dev, libcurl4-openssl-dev

How can I get rid of that error? EVP_PKEY_base_id is somehow not available anymore on my machine.

Comment: The documentation does *not* say that function was deprecated. It was *renamed* to EVP_PKEY_get_base_id with a compatibility macro to map from the old name to the new name. I'm not familiar with swift but it looks to me like that compatibility macro isn't working for swift. Perhaps try the new name?

Comment: Thank you, that's true... I thought Swift would access the local system library, but as you said the compatibility macro does not work. How can I debug it locally? Maybe a missing lib on my machine?

Comment: Like I said I'm not familiar with swift so can't assist with debugging it